# Momentum representation of a function with discontinuous derivative

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, fourier-transform

Consider the following wave packet $$\psi = Ce^{2\pi i p_0x/h}e^{-|x|/(2\Delta x)}$$
where $h$ is the Planck's constant and $C$ is the normalization constant.

The derivative of this function is discontinuous at 0. How do I obtain the momentum space?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\Delta x$? Anyway, in principle, the Fourier transform extends to a unitary of $L^2$, hence as long as your function is $L^2$ (which I guess it is), you have a Fourier transform and you can calculate it the usual way.

Comment: $\Delta x$ is the standard deviation, I think. But it doesn't make mathematical sense because of discontinuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the position representation and the momentum representation are related by (the unitary) Fourier transform, which is an integral transform, there is no problem in determining the momentum space wave function from the function you're considering.

You've indicated the homework tag so I won't completely answer the question now. But here is a hint that should get you moving in the right direction. *Hint:* Use a fundamental property of integration regarding the composition of integrals over disjoint segments of the domain of integration. That is, if you are computing
\begin{align}
\psi(p) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dp}{2\pi}e^{ipx}\psi(x)
\end{align}
you can consider
\begin{align}
\psi(p) &= \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{dp}{2\pi}e^{ipx}\psi(x)
+\int_0^\infty \frac{dp}{2\pi}e^{ipx}\psi(x).
\end{align}

Don't take this to mean that there isn't something unusual or maybe even ``wrong'' with the wave function. What happens to the current at $x=0$. What about the second derivative. Answer these questions and you're on your way to understanding an interesting problem.

Comment: I tried doing that. That was my first 'strategy'. Higher order derivatives? I found a paper on this on arxiv.org but I am not sure if that really applies to the question. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.4244.pdf

Comment: Hi Artemisia - yes, the paper you cite is relevant. But it is also fairly complicated. Why don't you do two things: 1) Compute the derivative of your wave function for two limits: $\lim_{x\to 0^\pm}$. 2) Follow the advice of David Z, above, and show some of your work. Best of luck.